# Dynamically Populate one drop down based on selection in other drop down

Tags: javascript, html

I have a drop down button for selecting the gender (Male or female) and another drop down button for selecting marital status.

When selecting gender as male, then the marital status drop down button should list out:

- unmarried
- married
- divorced, and
- **widower**

When selecting gender as female the marital status drop down button should populate:

- unmarried
- married
- divorced, and
- **widow**

Based on the selection in the first drop down button, the contents of second drop down button should change.

Can anyone help me do this?

Comment: Just use "widowed". As well as being gender-neutral, it is grammatically consistent with your other choices, unmarried, married and divorced. These are all states (adjectives or strictly speaking participles), while widow/widower are nouns.

Comment: @Verbeia, you're right. But I guess the question warrants a technical answer anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UPDATE:
 add `id="gender"` and `onchange="updateMaritalStatus(this)"` to the first select

```
   <select id="gender" onchange="updateMaritalStatus(this)">
```

keep the second select option on one line

```
   <select id="marital"><option>Unmarried</option><option>Married</option><option>Divorced</option><option>Widow</option></select>
```

function for onload/onchange

```
 function updateMaritalStatus(o){

  var gen = document.getElementById("gender"), marital_status = "";

  if(o){
      marital_status = o.value == "m" ? " widower" : "widow"
  }else{
   marital_status = gen.selectedIndex == 0 ? "widower" : "widow";
  } 
     document.getElementById("marital").lastChild.text  = marital_status;
  }
```

add `onload` the change the widow/widower

```
  window.onload = function (){updateMaritalStatus()};
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use **widowed**?  It matches the tense of the other selections.

Comment: The requirement given to me is, if we are selecting male then drop down should be widower and if am selecting female it should be widow

Comment: @Radhika this is one case where it's worth getting back to the business analyst and clarifying the requirements.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of switching out the entire list, what about just switching the last element instead?

```
<select>
    <option class="gender" value="m">Male</option>
    <option class="gender" value="f">Female</option>
</select>

<select id="marital">
    <option>Unmarried</option>
    <option>Married</option>
    <option>Divorced</option>
    <option>Widow</option>
</select>
```

Now, using jQuery to simplify the Javascript (you can convert to pure JS if you would prefer):

```
$('.gender').click(function(){
    var w = $('#marital').children().last();

    if( $(this).attr('value') == 'm' )
    {
        w.text('Widower');
    }
    else
    {
        w.text('Widow');
    }
});
```

That should create the effect you're looking for.